# How to use select and insert in combination with some parameter values in T-SQL?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

```
INSERT INTO ProjectWorkflowAgg(ProjectCode,Priority,ApprovalType)
    SELECT MasterCode,Priority,ApprovalTitle FROM WFPolicyDetails where MasterCode = @WFPolicyID ORDER BY Priority ASC;
```

I have successfully implemented the above mentioned query. Now there is a parameter value SRFID, which I am providing it directly. How to modify the above query to insert the SRFID parameter value as well along with the values of select command. Or there is any other alternative way to achieve this?

```
INSERT INTO ProjectWorkflowAgg(ProjectCode,Priority,ApprovalType,PolicyMasterCode=@SRFID)
SELECT MasterCode,Priority,ApprovalTitle FROM WFPolicyDetails
where MasterCode = @WFPolicyID ORDER BY Priority ASC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameter to the `SELECT` statement

```
INSERT INTO  ProjectWorkflowAgg(ProjectCode,Priority,ApprovalType,PolicyMasterCode)
SELECT MasterCode, Priority, ApprovalTitle, @SRFID 
FROM WFPolicyDetails
WHERE MasterCode = @WFPolicyID
```